# Using getElementById on nav ul li a style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a style in a css file like this for a drop down menu,

```
nav ul li a 
        {
            display: block; 
            padding: 5px 4px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            color: #64FFFF; 
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

and I wanted to change it with the DOM using something like this

```
var TAG = document.getElementById("nav ul li a");
TAG.setAttribute("style", "padding: 25px 40px;");
```

But it doesn't work, is it possible to do this or do I need another method.I can see I have four different tags to reference but how is that possible with JavaScript. Do I find the parent class and work my way down somehow?

Comment: `nav ul li a` is not a Element Id

Comment: I know, but is there a way to access that anchor tag through those other tags?

Comment: I'd recommend jQuery.

Comment: @Ruud 100KB library for a mere bytes of code? NO

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? only because OP didn't got what he was doing? He shared the code, he clearly explained the question, so on what basis we are downvoting?

Comment: @Mr.Alien yeah exactly. It's SO for you. We can tell he's new so we can help him out, it sucks how some people just downvote for the sake of it. Yes his code would be a downvoted question usually for me, though being new here and telling he's new I instead took the liberty to explain it to the OP. like you did.Also upvoted your answer too, since we were the first lol

Comment: @EasyBB Yes and I commented the same on your answer lol :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien: This is one on me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question Sorry about that, I just meant to point out that jQuery's selectors are a good match for the original question. I never meant to start a pros/cons discussion; there's enough of those already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using jQuery like selector, you need to provide an `ID` as you are using `getElementById`

```
var TAG = document.getElementById("hello");
TAG.setAttribute("style", "padding: 25px 40px;");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k46L2/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/k46L2/1/) *(Nothing fancy, just used `color` property instead of `padding` so that effects are visible)*

Markup would look something like

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="hello">hello</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById` searches for ID

`document.getElementsByTagName` searches for tag names and returns an array that matches

`document.getElementsByClassName` searches for class names and returns an array that matches

Now if you want to do it like jQuery `document.querySelectorAll` is what you are looking for.

And in which turn will return an array. So you'd need to loop through it

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('nav ul li a');
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  a[i].setAttribute('style','padding:25px 40px'); // a[i].style.padding="25px 40px";
}
 /*
  another way to loop which is partially faster
  var len = a.length;
  while(len--){
   a[len].setAttribute('style','padding:25px 40px");
   }
 */
```

Comment: Somehow jquery scares me but plus one for the info!

Comment: No problem. jQuery is a newbie grabber. Though it does help as it has certain polyfills for cross browser compatibility.

Comment: I added an upvote as people are down voting you. It's ok, it'll happen. Though I can tell you are new at JavaScript so I'll try to help you out :D

Comment: @EasyBB I voted as well, I don't know what's wrong, research efforts may be applied here but anyone can clear doubts by posting question

Comment: @Mr.Alien Exactly my thoughts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css selector with `querySelectorAll()` to fetch the matched elements, something like this in your case.

```
var tag = document.querySelectorAll('nav ul li a');
    tag[0].setAttribute("style", "padding: 250px 40px;");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use another approach. I let the browser do the ccs matching for me and just add a class on the nav element.

```
nav ul li a 
    {
        display: block; 
        padding: 5px 4px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        color: #64FFFF; 
        text-decoration: none;
    }
nav.alternate ul li a
    {
        padding: 25px 40px;
    }
```

Your javascript (assumes that there is only one tag nav and that it doesn't have a class yet) :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0].className = "alternate"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not get element in this way,you have to give a unique id to each a tag and then get element in following way

```
var Tag=document.getElementById('uniqueId');
```

To get element/s without specifying id, you have to use jQuery in following way

```
var element=jQuery(".nav ul li a");

element.css('padding','25px 40px');
```